# Bring Vertical Table to Horizontal in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have this table:

```
+----+------+
| ID | NAME |
+----+------+
|  1 | A    |
|  1 | B    |
|  1 | C    |
|  2 | A    |
|  2 | P    |
|  2 | D    |
|  2 | X    |
|  3 | F    |
|  3 | 45   |
+----+------+
```

and i want to transform it to this. (The ID will be unique and the Names for each reoccurring ID of the same ID will be added in a new field.

```
+----+------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | NAME | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 |
+----+------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | A    | B     | C     |       |
|  2 | A    | P     | D     | X     |
|  3 | F    | 45    |       |       |
+----+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Is there a fast way to do this in Access. VBA code is ok. I have tried Pivot and transpose (in Excel) both do not work, or do not give me the desired result. Empty cells like (first row Name3) are ok. Any suggestions, links or code snippets are much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you something similar:

```sql
TRANSFORM FIRST([Name]) AS FirstOfName
SELECT ID
FROM
    (
        SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, 'Name' & Format(COUNT(*),"000") AS NewName
        FROM
            YourTable AS t1
            INNER JOIN
            YourTable AS t2
                ON t1.ID = t2.ID
                    AND t1.Name >= t2.Name
        GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.Name
    )
GROUP BY ID
PIVOT NewName
```

For test data in [YourTable]

```
ID  Name
--  ----
 1  A   
 1  B   
 1  C   
 2  A   
 2  P   
 2  D   
 2  X   
 3  F   
 3  45
```

it returns

```
ID  Name001  Name002  Name003  Name004
--  -------  -------  -------  -------
 1  A        B        C           
 2  A        D        P        X    
 3  45       F
```

Comment: That was fast, great! the Fields are in the order Name1, Name10, Name11, Name 12, ... Name19, Name2... 
Would it be possible to change that?